# Convert a Pandas Core Series with Dictionary in Rows into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Pandas Core series called "series_1" which has dictionaries of three variables ("V-Ratio", "Z-score", "P") in each row. It looks like this:

```
V1    [{'V-Ratio': 0.98, 'Z-score': -0.94, 'P': 0.17}]
V2    [{'V-Ratio': 0.97, 'Z-score': -1.34, 'P': 0.09}]
V3     [{'V-Ratio': 1.03, 'Z-score': 1.21, 'P': 0.89}]
V4     [{'V-Ratio': 1.04, 'Z-score': 1.41, 'P': 0.92}]
V5    [{'V-Ratio': 0.99, 'Z-score': -0.42, 'P': 0.34}]
V6    [{'V-Ratio': 0.96, 'Z-score': -1.72, 'P': 0.04}]
V7      [{'V-Ratio': 1.02, 'Z-score': 0.7, 'P': 0.76}]
V8    [{'V-Ratio': 0.97, 'Z-score': -1.09, 'P': 0.14}]
V9     [{'V-Ratio': 0.98, 'Z-score': -0.7, 'P': 0.24}]
V10     [{'V-Ratio': 0.76, 'Z-score': -9.31, 'P': 0.0}]
V11     [{'V-Ratio': 0.83, 'Z-score': -6.74, 'P': 0.0}]
V12    [{'V-Ratio': 0.92, 'Z-score': -3.14, 'P': 0.0}]
V13     [{'V-Ratio': 0.92, 'Z-score': -3.23, 'P': 0.0}]
V14     [{'V-Ratio': 0.87, 'Z-score': -4.99, 'P': 0.0}]
V15     [{'V-Ratio': 1.02, 'Z-score': 0.75, 'P': 0.77}]
V16       [{'V-Ratio': 0.9, 'Z-score': -3.7, 'P': 0.0}]
V17     [{'V-Ratio': 0.95, 'Z-score': -2.1, 'P': 0.02}]
```

I would like to convert it into a Pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

```
    V-Ratio Z-score  P
V1  0.98   -0.94    0.17
V2  0.97    1.34    0.09
V3  1.03    1.21    0.89
V4  1.04    1.41    0.92
V5  0.99   -0.42    0.34
.........................
.........................
.........................
```

What I have Tried:

1. "series = pd.DataFrame(series_1)" gives me a dataframe with one column which has the dictionaries containing the variables in the rows.
2. "series = pd.DataFrame([series_1])" doesn't achieve my results.
3. "series = pd.DataFrame(series_1, index=[0])" doesn't work.

Does anyone have any clues on how I can fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

column represents the column name where you have list of dictionary.

```
df = df[column].apply(pd.Series)[0].apply(pd.Series)
```

Output

```
    V-Ratio Z-score P
V1  0.98    -0.94   0.17
V2  0.97    -1.34   0.09
V3  1.03    1.21    0.89
V4  1.04    1.41    0.92
V5  0.99    -0.42   0.34
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that, each of V1, V2, ... is a list of dictionaries, however each with only 1 element in the list.
Ideally, you would want something like

`[{'V-Ratio': 0.98, 'Z-score': -0.94, 'P': 0.17}, {'V-Ratio': 0.97, 'Z-score': -1.34, 'P': 0.09}, ....]`, each element corresponding to `V1`, `V2` etc. but you have `[[{'V-Ratio': 0.98, 'Z-score': -0.94, 'P': 0.17}], [{'V-Ratio': 0.97, 'Z-score': -1.34, 'P': 0.09}], ....]`  Please check that out.
After that, you can try the steps you did, or convert the Series to list using `.tolist()` and converting to dataframe.

If you are not able to change that, you would have to convert only the first element of the list of each series to convert to a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try this You need to get first `dict` from your `list`

```py
# here, `s` is your series
df = s.str[0].apply(pd.Series)      
df
    V-Ratio  Z-score     P
v1     0.98    -0.94  0.17
v2     0.97    -1.34  0.09
v3     1.03     1.21  0.89
......
```

or

```
df = s.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[0]))
```